# Apache Flink and the Zookeeper high availability doesn't work as expected

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zookeeper, high-availability

I have deployed an standalone flink( 1.15.0) cluster with 3 masters and i am using Zookeeper(3.5.0) to provide high availability. Here i share my flink.yml configuration:

```
high-availability: zookeeper
high-availability.storageDir: s3://bucket-name/flink
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: zookeeper-dns:2181
state.checkpoints.dir: s3://bucket-name/flink/checkpoints
high-availability.cluster-id: flinkId
```

The problem is when for some reason all 3 jobmanagers fail, for example the first 1 stops and then starts again, then the second one stops and starts again and when the third one stops, the taskmanagers can't connect anymore to job managers.

I can see this logs:

```
2022-09-01 23:22:50,616 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.DefaultLeaderRetrievalService [] - Starting DefaultLeaderRetrievalService with ZookeeperLeaderRetrievalDriver{connectionInformationPath='/resource_manager/connection_info'}.
2022-09-01 23:22:50,626 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.DefaultLeaderRetrievalService [] - Starting DefaultLeaderRetrievalService with ZookeeperLeaderRetrievalDriver{connectionInformationPath='/dispatcher/connection_info'}.

2022-09-01 23:22:50,698 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                   2022-09-01 23:22:50,705 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                       [] - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:50505] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:50505]] Caused by: [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:50505]
2022-09-01 23:22:50,698 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                   2022-09-01 23:22:50,705 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                       [] - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:50505] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:50505]] Caused by: [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:50505]
```

Comment: It would be interesting to get the entire JobManager logs and not only the snippet to understand what's going on. On side note: Having three JobManager processes doesn't add much value. Only if you want to cover the fact that two JobManager go down at the same time.

Comment: The problem was solved, but let me explain you the issue an what we have done to fixed. Imagine that you have 2 (A and B) jobmanager and for any reason the jobmanager(A) leader fails the second jobmanager(B) will become the new leader. After 30 seconds the jobmanger(A) that has failed will start again and will be in standby state. We have 2 jobmanager running so far, if the jobamanger(B) leader fails is suppost that the jobmanager(A) in standby should become the new leader, but that doesn't happens, and the flink cluster fails.

Comment: The param  jobmanager.rpc.address wasn't configured in the flink.yml file, becasue the documentation says:  This value is not used in many high-availability setups, when a leader-election service (like ZooKeeper) is used to elect and discover the JobManager leader from potentially multiple standby JobManagers. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/config/#jobmanager-rpc-address

Comment: It seems the problem is when only a jobmanager is running.  To solve it we had to configure the param jobmanager.rpc.address for each jobmanager.